# How can I add custom code to Webflow Templates?

Tags: webflow

I have a website on Webflow, and the articles on the site are made in templates. I need to add microdata to custom code. How can I do it?

In the Webflow support, I was told that it's possible to add a block for writing custom code in the editor, but it is not available there.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing custom code in Webflow is straightforward, and the two easiest methods to do so are:

1. The Webflow Editor: Follow the steps outlined [here](https://university.webflow.com/lesson/custom-code-embed) to seamlessly integrate custom code using the editor.
2. Head and Body Tags: For more control, you can add custom code directly to the head and body tags. Find detailed instructions [here](https://university.webflow.com/lesson/custom-code-in-the-head-and-body-tags).

These approaches should work for most scenarios, as they offer flexibility based on your preferences and project requirements.